Why Shader editor doesn't show any node?
As you can see in the image i have an object selected with its current material selected, however, there is no Principal BSDF in the shader editor, actually there is nothing... I know that i can press SHIFT A to add them, but where are the nods of the already existing material? BLENDER VERSION 4.1 ( i am not going to switch to newer version )
Thanks
Pedro


Hello, judging by the the size and location of elevator handles in the lower left and top right corners of the shader editors I think you will find your nodes if you scroll to the lower right. or hit A > .

Try pressing Home while your mouse cursor is over the Shader Editor. This will “Frame all” nodes. If it still shows nothing, either the Shader Editor is really empty, or you are experiencing a graphical error.

Thanks that worked!
